# How to pass argument from component to redux action

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, thunk

I'm trying to pass the country name to the action in Redux from the React component but when it arrives in the action creator it becomes undefined. I think its something to do with the mapDispatchToProps() section below the component but I'm quite new to Redux so I'm not entirely sure.

It gets the list of countries from the API ok but then when I want to pass the selected country back up to Actions.js the country becomes undefined.

Component.js

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import {
  getCountryCasesAction,
  getAllAvailableCountriesAction,
} from "../redux/Actions";

import { Form } from "semantic-ui-react";

function CasesByCountry({
  countryOptions,
  getAllAvailableCountries,
  getCountryCases,
}) {
  useEffect(() => {
    getAllAvailableCountries();
  }, [getAllAvailableCountries]);

  const onDropdownOptionSelect = (e, result, country, countryData) => {
    console.log(result.value);
    getCountryCases(result.value);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Form.Dropdown
        placeholder="Select Country"
        fluid
        selection
        search
        onChange={onDropdownOptionSelect}
        options={
          countryOptions &&
          countryOptions.map((c) => {
            return {
              key: c.ISO2,
              text: c.Country,
              value: c.Country,
            };
          })
        }
      />
    </div>
  );
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    countryOptions: state.data,
    countryData: state.data,
  };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = {
  getAllAvailableCountries: getAllAvailableCountriesAction,
  getCountryCases: getCountryCasesAction,
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(CasesByCountry);
```

Actions.js

```
import axios from "axios";

export const GET_WORLDWIDE_SUMMARY = "GET_WORLDWIDE_SUMMARY";
export const GET_COUNTRY_CASES = "GET_COUNTRY_CASES";
export const GET_ALL_AVAILABLE_COUNTRIES = "GET_ALL_COUNTRIES";

export const getWorldwideSummaryAction = () => async (dispatch, getState) => {
  // const response = await axios
  //   .get
  //   // "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/" +
  //   // "process.env.REACT_APP_GET_WORLDWIDE_SUMMARY"
  //   ();
  // console.log(response);
  // return dispatch({
  //   type: GET_WORLDWIDE_SUMMARY,
  //   payload: response.data,
  // });
};

export const getAllAvailableCountriesAction = () => async (
  dispatch,
  getState
) => {
  const response = await axios.get("https://api.covid19api.com/countries");
  console.log(response);

  return dispatch({
    type: GET_ALL_AVAILABLE_COUNTRIES,
    payload: response.data,
  });
};

export const getCountryCasesAction = () => async (
  dispatch,
  getState,
  country
) => {
  console.log("getCountryCasesAction");
  const response = await axios.get(
    `https://api.covid19api.com/dayone/country/${country}/status/confirmed`
  );
  console.log(response);
  return dispatch({
    type: GET_COUNTRY_CASES,
    payload: response.data,
  });
};
```

Reducer.js

```
import {
  GET_WORLDWIDE_SUMMARY,
  GET_ALL_AVAILABLE_COUNTRIES,
  GET_COUNTRY_CASES,
} from "./Actions";

const initialState = {
  data: "",
};

export const rootReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case GET_WORLDWIDE_SUMMARY:
      console.log(action.payload);
      return {
        ...state,
        data: action.payload,
      };

    case GET_ALL_AVAILABLE_COUNTRIES:
      console.log(action.payload);
      return {
        ...state,
        data: action.payload,
      };

    case GET_COUNTRY_CASES:
      console.log(action.payload);
      return {
        ...state,
        data: action.payload,
      };

    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

Comment: What's the result of `console.log(response);` inside `getCountryCasesAction()` ?

Comment: It logs the country i select from the dropdown menu, that's what I want to pass to Actions.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try dispatching your action like this?

```js
//actions.js
export const getCountryCasesAction = (country) => async (
  dispatch,
  getState
) => {
  const response = await axios.get(
    `https://api.covid19api.com/dayone/country/${country}/status/confirmed`
  );
  console.log("CountryCaseAction", response);
  return dispatch({
    type: GET_COUNTRY_CASES,
    payload: response.data,
  });
};
```

```js
//CasesByCountry.js
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import {
  getCountryCasesAction,
  getAllAvailableCountriesAction,
} from "../redux/Actions";

import { Form } from "semantic-ui-react";

function CasesByCountry() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const availableCountries = useSelector((state) => state.availableCountries);
  const countryCases = useSelector((state) => state.countryCases);

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getAllAvailableCountriesAction());
  }, [dispatch]);

  const optionForCountries =
    availableCountries &&
    availableCountries.map((country) => {
      return {
        key: country.ISO2,
        text: country.Country,
        value: country.Country,
      };
    });

  console.log(countryCases);

  return (
    <div>
      <Form.Dropdown
        placeholder="Select Country"
        fluid
        selection
        search
        onChange={(result, e) => dispatch(getCountryCasesAction(e.value))}
        options={optionForCountries}
      />
    </div>
  );
}

export default CasesByCountry;
```

```js
//reducer.js
import {
  GET_WORLDWIDE_SUMMARY,
  GET_ALL_AVAILABLE_COUNTRIES,
  GET_COUNTRY_CASES,
} from "./Actions";

const initialState = {
  data: "",
  availableCountries: "",
  countryCases: "",
};

export const rootReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case GET_WORLDWIDE_SUMMARY:
      return {
        ...state,
        data: action.payload,
      };

    case GET_ALL_AVAILABLE_COUNTRIES:
      return {
        ...state,
        availableCountries: action.payload,
      };

    case GET_COUNTRY_CASES:
      return {
        ...state,
        countryCases: action.payload,
      };

    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211592/discussion-on-answer-by-ajin-kabeer-how-to-pass-argument-from-component-to-redux).

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you're passing in the country property the wrong way.

I've made a few changes in CaseByCountry.js file

```
...

  return (
    <div>
      <Form.Dropdown
        placeholder="Select Country"
        fluid
        selection
        search
        onChange={(result, e) => getCountryCases(e.value)}
        //{(result) => dispatch(getCountryCases(result.value))}
        options={
          countryOptions &&
          countryOptions.map((c) => {
            return {
              key: c.ISO2,
              text: c.Country,
              value: c.Country,
            };
          })
        }
      />
    </div>
  );
}
 ...

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
  getAllAvailableCountries: () => dispatch(getAllAvailableCountriesAction),
  getCountryCases: country => dispatch(getCountryCasesAction(country)),
});
```

Also, changes in Actions.js file

```
export const getCountryCasesAction = (country) => async (
  dispatch,
  getState
) => {
  console.log("getCountryCasesAction", country);
  const response = await axios.get(
    `https://api.covid19api.com/dayone/country/${country}/status/confirmed`
  );
  console.log(response);
  return dispatch({
    type: GET_COUNTRY_CASES,
    payload: response.data,
  });
};
```

Country is not undefined anymore. But there's a new error occurring. Since it is not in the scope of the question, I simply left it alone.

Note that I only copied the part that I made changes.

Comment: Please, let me know whether or not the solution is working.

Comment: Okay thanks, I suppose technically you answered the question  I'll just try to figure out how to solve the new problem now haha I think I should be able to so thanks :)

Comment: Okay. Good luck.